# Error message: "Cannot connect to Gmail"

Tags: google-apps-script

Sometimes I get this error message from time-based trigger of many scripts ...
There is something I can do or is only a server-side issue ?

Comment: yes its only serverside issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a server-side indeed. But it is expect that it fails now and then. I guess you should implement an [exponential backoff](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com.br/2011/12/documents-list-api-best-practices.html). [Here](https://gist.github.com/2700284) is an Apps Script implementation by [Peter Herrmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298650).

Comment: @Henrique Thanks for the mention :) I've simplified the function and posted here https://gist.github.com/2700284

Comment: @PeterHerrmann I'm just wonder if you can write a very simple lib with this function and share it with us :)

Comment: @edo OK, I've published it as a library called GASRetry. You can add it to your own code in the IDE by accessing Resources > Manage Libraries... and pasting the GASRetry project key: MGJu3PS2ZYnANtJ9kyn2vnlLDhaBgl_dE

Comment: @PeterHerrmann from version 4 to version 10 in less than 24 hours ? wow :)

Comment: One new feature (logging) but mainly I was dealing with making the doc and examples useful and fighting lots of edge cases with the doc generator (logged a bug to the gas team too). The feature to use a logger works with Logger.log but also with my new lib GASLog (works like Log4j but no code examples there yet). https://docs.google.com/macros/library/versions/d/MQoBNVXrMoUHZFGi5x39pylLDhaBgl_dE

Comment: man, I'm falling in love with you :D You must share a spreadsheet with links of your libraries ;)

Comment: @edo There is a wider issue already reported re this and I have added my details http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1459. Please look/post there re a workaround and make sure to "star" the issue too please.